# Hover function doesn't want to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

i've been trying to make a code that makes a div containing a description show when hovering over its parent li, but it just wont work..

I'm almost certain that it has something to do with the structure or the css.

jQuery:

```
$('.featured_entry li').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('.description').show(100); 
}, function() {
   $(this).find('.description').hide(100);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="featured_entry">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="description">blabalbla</div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
}

.description {
    background: #142450;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;

    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy3wW/9/

Comment: Works for me after I added jQuery to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7yucd/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP simple didn't set up jsFiddle properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy3wW/10/

this is working. You forgot to add the jquery library. You just need to add:
    `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

to your file

as well as a .ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* jquery code */ });
```

Comment: Wow, thank you.. I have my code in a foundation 4 document that i've made into wordpress and it seems as the jquery from foundation doesn't work.. Again, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to defer execution until the DOM is loaded as well:

```
$(function(){
    $('.featured_entry li').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('.description').show(100); 
         }, function() {
            $(this).find('.description').hide(100);
     });
});
```